# Open my application from safari when user enters my webpage url

Tags: ios, url, safari

I want to know if I can add my website URL (e.g. www.example.com/mypage OR www.example.com/mypage?q=value) in URL scheme of Xcode so that if user types in URL to my website then app opens directly.

I know that custom URL scheme works e.g. 'myapp://'